# Docker make .sh executable and run it

Tags: docker

I'm trying to give executable permission to my script inside docker image and run it. I don't want to set chmod + x for it in Dockerfile.
i tried

> docker run img /bin/bash -c "chmod +x ../test/test.sh; ../test/test.sh

but i got "/bin/bash: bad interpreter: Text file busy"

and i can't just make two containers with this commands:

> docker run -d img chmod +x ../test/test.sh
>
> docker run -d img ../test/test.sh

=> starting container process caused "exec: \"../test/testing.sh\": permission denied"

i need somehow bind this two containers together

Answer (score 1):

`Text file busy` means that something is already using the file.

Normally this would work

```
docker run --rm -it alpine sh -c 'echo "echo it works" > test.sh && chmod +x test.sh && ./test.sh'
```

With the second command you create two new containers, that are completly seperate. If you want to execute something in an running container you can use `docker exec -it <container id or name> <command e.g. bash>`

Comment: the thing is nothing uses it- i've tried to create new image and use this command- it returned with that err. it can be only used by chmod command(i replaced chmod command before semicolon with echo and got "permission denied". i've also tried  docker run -d img chmod +x ../test/testing.sh and then docker exec -it container ../test/testing.sh - and i got Container container is not running.. despite the detached mode of my container with chmod..

Comment: The container exits after `docker run -d img chmod +x ../test/testing.sh` because there is no process running and you have to use chmod if you don't want to use `sh test.sh`. Can you post the Dockerfile to look why it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've figured it:

first i made a container:

```
docker run --name CONTAINER -dt IMAGE
```

then exec my commands:

```
docker exec CONTAINER chmod +x ../test/test.sh 

docker exec CONTAINER ../test/test.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set perms if you just pass your script as parameter:

```
docker run -d IMAGE /bin/bash ../test/test.sh
```

(add `-i` and/or `-t` if you need them)